# Saving timer state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I need to make sure that when the page is refreshed, the task time is not reset to the original, but is kept current.
I have code(Timer component):

```
function Timer({ itemtask, setUpdateTime }) {
  const [startAt, setStartAt] = useState();
  const [initialTimer, setInitialTimer] = useState(0);

  function useNow(updateInterval, enabled, cb) {
    const cbRef = useRef(cb);
    cbRef.current = cb;
    const [now, setNow] = useState(Date.now());

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
      if (!enabled) {
        return;
      }

      setNow(Date.now());

      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setNow(Date.now());
      }, updateInterval);

      // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
    }, [updateInterval, enabled]);
    return now;
  }

  const now = useNow(1000, startAt);
  const timeFromStart = now - (startAt ?? now);
  const timeInputValue = itemtask.minutes * 60000 + itemtask.seconds * 1000;
  const timer = timeFromStart + initialTimer;
  const countDown = timeInputValue - timer;

  const isCountEnd = countDown < 0 && itemtask.minutes !== 0 && itemtask.seconds !== 0;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isCountEnd && timeInputValue) {
      alert(`${itemtask.task} completed`);
    }
  }, [isCountEnd]);

  const toggleTimer = () => {
    if (startAt) {
      setUpdateTime(itemtask.id, countDown);
      setInitialTimer(timer);
      setStartAt();
    } else {
      setStartAt(Date.now());
    }
  };

  function msToTime(duration) {
    if (duration < 0) {
      return 'Times up';
    }

    let seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60);
    let minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
    return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  }

  return (
    <div className="timer">
      <PlayCircleTwoTone
        onClick={() => {
          toggleTimer();
        }}
        twoToneColor="#cc9a9a"
        style={{ fontSize: '32px' }}
      />
      <span>{itemtask.minutes || itemtask.seconds ? msToTime(countDown) : msToTime(timer)}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

setUpdateTime function:

```
const setUpdateTime = (id, time) => {
    const seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((time / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    const newArr = arrayTasks.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          minutes,
          seconds,
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
    setArrayTasks(newArr);
  };
```

By calling toggleTimer I save the current state of the timer using setUpdateTimer.
In this case, the time is saved in the task, but the time is displayed that differs by a few seconds (for the time that has passed)

As I understand it, the matter is in updating setInitialTimer (timer), but this is not accurate ..

Comment: _when the page is refreshed, the task time is not reset to the original_ you could 'save' the time(s) in localstorage

Comment: @RubenSmn, thx, I solved the problem by changing the line in toggleTimer: `setInitialTimer((prev) => prev);`